# Show that for all $x>0, P \big ( \exists n>0: \sum_{k=1}^n X_k\ge x) \le e^{-tx}$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let be $(X_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ a sequence of independent and identically distributed random variables.

There is a $t>0$ so that
$\mathbb{E}(e^{tX_1})=1 $.

Show that for all $x>0, 
P \big ( \exists n>0: \sum_{k=1}^n X_k\ge x) \le e^{-tx}$

My idea is that I could eventually use the Chebyshev's inequality but I'm totally struggling how can I solve this problem. I would really appreciate any kind of your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $Y_{n}:=e^{t\sum_{k=1}^{n}X_{k}}=\prod_{k=1}^{n}e^{tX_{k}}$, then $Y$ is a *nonnegative* martingale, as
$$\mathbb{E}[Y_{n+1}|\mathcal{F}_{n}]=\mathbb{E}[Y_{n}e^{tX_{n+1}}|\mathcal{F}_{n}]=Y_{n}\mathbb{E}[e^{tX_{n+1}}]=Y_{n}.$$
Also note that $\{\exists n>0:\sum_{k=1}^{n}X_{k}\geq x\}=\{\exists n>0:Y_{n}\geq e^{tx}\}=\{\max_{1\leq i\leq n}Y_{i}\geq e^{tx}\}$, Doob's martingale inequality gives
$$\mathbb{P}\Bigl(\max_{1\leq i\leq n}Y_{i}\geq e^{tx}\Bigr)\leq\frac{\mathbb{E}[Y_{n}^{+}]}{e^{tx}}=\frac{\mathbb{E}[Y_{1}]}{e^{tx}}=\frac{1}{e^{tx}}.$$